# A long table with rotated texts?

Tags: tables, rotating, scaling

Here is the code for the table below

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kpfonts,pifont}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array,multirow,amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\textbf {\large Course Outline}:
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.02\textwidth}|p{0.84\textwidth}|}
\hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter }    & \textbf{Content} \\
\hline
\parbox[t]{5mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Chapter 1}}}  & \begin{minipage}{.85\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{254}] \itemsep-0.4em
    \vspace{1mm}
    \item Properties of inverse functions
    \item Derivative of inverse functions
    \item Inverses of trigonometric functions and their derivatives
    \item Exponential and logarithmic functions
    \item Exponential growth and decay
    \item Inverse of hyperbolic functions and their derivatives
    \item Exponential and logarithmic functions
    \item Exponential growth and decay
    \item Inverse of hyperbolic functions and their derivatives
    \vspace{1mm}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}  \\
\hline
\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Chapter 2}}}   & \begin{minipage}{.85\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{254}] \itemsep-0.4em
    \vspace{1mm}
    \item Elementary integration formulas
    \item Integration by parts
    \item Integration by trigonometric substitution
    \item Integration by partial fractions
    \item Trigonometric integrals
    \item Trapezoidal and Simpson's rule
    \item Application of integration (area, volume, arc length, surface area)
    \vspace{1mm}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage} \\ \hline
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Chapter 3}   & \begin{minipage}{.85\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{254}] \itemsep-0.4em
    \vspace{1mm}
    \item Indeterminate forms (L' H\^opital's Rule)
    \item Improper integrals
    \item Taylor's formula
    \item Approximation by Taylor's polynomial
    \vspace{1mm}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage} \\
\hline
\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{18}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Chapter 4}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Sequence and series (30 hrs)}}}   & \begin{minipage}{.85\textwidth}
\vspace{1mm}
Sequences
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{254}] \itemsep-0.4em
    \item Convergence and divergence of sequences
    \item Properties of convergent sequences
    \item Bounded and monotonic sequences
    \vspace{1mm}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage} \\
  & \begin{minipage}{.85\textwidth}
\vspace{1mm}
Infinite series
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{254}] \itemsep-0.4em
    \item Definition of infinite series
    \item Convergence and divergence of series
    \item Properties of convergent series
    \item Convergence tests for positive term series (integral, comparison, ratio, root)
    \item Alternating series
    \item Absolute convergence, conditional convergence
    \item Generalized convergence tests
    \vspace{1mm}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage} \\
& \begin{minipage}{.85\textwidth}
\vspace{1mm}
Power series
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{254}] \itemsep-0.4em
    \item Definition of power series
    \item Convergence and divergence, radius and interval of convergence
    \item Algebraic operations on convergent power series
    \item Differentiation and integration of a power series
    \item Taylor \& Maclaurin series
    \item Binomial Theorem
    \vspace{1mm}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage} \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to insert "

- "Inverse Functions(12hrs)" below(vertically) Chapter 1,
- "Techniques of Integration (12hrs)" below Chapter 2,
- "L'hopital's Rule \& Indeterminate forms" below Chapter 3.

(Like "Sequence and Series(30hrs)" is blow Chapter 4) while the table is fitted to one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another variant, based on `tabularx` and `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kpfonts,pifont}
\usepackage{longtable, tabularx, makecell}
\usepackage{array,multirow,amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\arraybackslash\compress}X}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash\compress}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\textbf {\large Course Outline}:\bigskip

\setlist[itemize]{label=\ding{254}, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt, before=\vspace*{\topsep}, after =\vspace*{-\topsep}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
\hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Content}} \\
\hline
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makecell{Chapter 1\\Inverse Functions \\ (12hrs)}}
 & \begin{itemize}
    \item Properties of inverse functions
    \item Derivative of inverse functions
    \item Inverses of trigonometric functions and their derivatives
    \item Exponential and logarithmic functions
    \item Exponential growth and decay
    \item Inverse of hyperbolic functions and their derivatives
    \item Exponential and logarithmic functions
    \item Exponential growth and decay
    \item Inverse of hyperbolic functions and their derivatives
\end{itemize}
\\
\hline
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makecell{Chapter 2\\ Techniques of \\Integration (12 hrs)}}
& \begin{itemize}
 \item Elementary integration formulas
 \item Integration by parts
 \item Integration by trigonometric substitution
 \item Integration by partial fractions
 \item Trigonometric integrals
 \item Trapezoidal and Simpson's rule
 \item Application of integration (area, volume, arc length, surface area)
\end{itemize}
 \\ \hline
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makecell{Chapter 3\\ L’Hôpital’s rule \\ \& Indeterminate\\ forms}}
 & \begin{itemize}
 \item Indeterminate forms (L' Hôpital's Rule)
 \item Improper integrals
 \item Taylor's formula
 \item Approximation by Taylor's polynomial
\end{itemize}\\
\hline
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makecell{Chapter 4\\Sequence and series\\ (30 hrs)}} & 
Sequences
\begin{itemize}[topsep = 2pt]
 \item Convergence and divergence of sequences
 \item Properties of convergent sequences
 \item Bounded and monotonic sequences
\end{itemize}
\medskip
Infinite series
\begin{itemize}[topsep = 2pt]
 \item Definition of infinite series
 \item Convergence and divergence of series
 \item Properties of convergent series
 \item Convergence tests for positive term series (integral, comparison, ratio, root)
 \item Alternating series
 \item Absolute convergence, conditional convergence
 \item Generalized convergence tests
\end{itemize}
\medskip
Power series
\begin{itemize}[topsep = 2pt]
 \item Definition of power series
 \item Convergence and divergence, radius and interval of convergence
 \item Algebraic operations on convergent power series
 \item Differentiation and integration of a power series
 \item Taylor \& Maclaurin series
 \item Binomial Theorem
\end{itemize} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The top-right corner of the table is "open". how can I close it? I tried to add `|` but it is not working.

Comment: @Marya: It's my fault, I forgot to check this point. Use `\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{content}}`. I've fixed  the code.

Answer (score 2):

with use of `makecell` and `rotating` package and after some tricks and manual tweaking (due to settings of `itemize` environment):

[image]

since your text at chapter 3 is to long to be fit in cell height' i made it shorter.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kpfonts, pifont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array,longtable,
            makecell,   % added
            multirow}
\makeatletter
\def\@rothead[#1]#2{\thead{\\[-.65\normalbaselineskip]
  \turn{\cellrotangle}\thead[#1]{#2}\endturn}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{rotating}   % added
\usepackage{setspace}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\textbf {\large Course Outline}:
\begingroup
    \setlist[itemize]{  nosep,
                        leftmargin=*,
                        label=\ding{254},
                        before=\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip},
                        after=\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}
                      }
%\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
%\renewcommand\cellalign{cc}
\begin{longtable}{|p{\dimexpr0.12\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                  |p{\dimexpr0.88\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
    \hline
 Chapter    & \textbf{Content} \\
\hline
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Inverse Functions (12hrs)}
\multirow{-1}{=}{\rothead[c]{Chapter 1\\ Inverse Functions (12hrs)}}
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Properties of inverse functions
    \item Derivative of inverse functions
    \item Inverses of trigonometric functions and their derivatives
    \item Exponential and logarithmic functions
    \item Exponential growth and decay
    \item Inverse of hyperbolic functions and their derivatives
    \item Exponential and logarithmic functions
    \item Exponential growth and decay
    \item Inverse of hyperbolic functions and their derivatives
        \end{itemize}   \\
\hline
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Inverse Functions (12hrs)}
\multirow{-1}{=}{\rothead[c]{Chapter 2\\Techniques of\\ Integration (12hrs)}}
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Elementary integration formulas
    \item Integration by parts
    \item Integration by trigonometric substitution
    \item Integration by partial fractions
    \item Trigonometric integrals
    \item Trapezoidal and Simpson's rule
    \item Application of integration (area, volume, arc length, surface area)
        \end{itemize}   \\
\hline
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Indeterminate}
\multirow{-1}{=}[1ex]{\rothead[c]{Chapter 3\\
                             L'hopital's\\
                             Rule}}
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Indeterminate forms (L' H\^opital's Rule)
    \item Improper integrals
    \item Taylor's formula
    \item Approximation by Taylor's polynomial
        \end{itemize}     \\
\hline
    &   Sequences         \\
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Sequence and series}
\multirow{16}{=}{\rothead[c]{Chapter 4\\
                            Sequence and series (30 hrs)}}
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Convergence and divergence of sequences
    \item Properties of convergent sequences
    \item Bounded and monotonic sequences
        \end{itemize}   \\
    &   Infinite series \\
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Definition of infinite series
    \item Convergence and divergence of series
    \item Properties of convergent series
    \item Convergence tests for positive term series (integral, comparison, ratio, root)
    \item Alternating series
    \item Absolute convergence, conditional convergence
    \item Generalized convergence tests
        \end{itemize}   \\
    &   Power series    \\
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Definition of power series
    \item Convergence and divergence, radius and interval of convergence
    \item Algebraic operations on convergent power series
    \item Differentiation and integration of a power series
    \item Taylor \& Maclaurin series
    \item Binomial Theorem
        \end{itemize}   \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```